# Scala - Map with default value None?

Tags: scala, dictionary, return-value

Given

```
trait A
case class B extends A

trait C
```

I'm trying to implement something akin to this:

```
val m = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, C=>Option[A]](
    ... //some pre-defined mappings
).withDefaultValue((_:C) => None)
```

This will give me a type mismatch:

> `expected: C=>Option[A], actual: C=>None.type`

I heard scala expects None to be returned from a catch clause, so I tried the very ugly

```
val m = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, C=>Option[A]](
    ... //some pre-defined mappings
).withDefaultValue((_:C) => try {
    throw new RuntimeException()
    Some(B())
  } catch{ case _ => None}
)
```

But that (thankfully) didn't work either:

> `type mismatch, expected: C=>Option[A], actual: C=>Option[B]`

What's the proper way to do what I am trying to?

Comment: Interesting. Please see my edited post. Does this change anything?

Comment: Nope, still compiles just fine. What version of scala are you using? Does `Option.empty[A]` work instead of `None`?

Comment: Well, turns out both are working for me as well, the error laid elsewhere. Thanks for Option.empty[A], though, that's what I was looking for. I do wonder why I can find it in the Option.scala but not in its documentation... probably just my being blind, again.

Comment: @User1291 - Check the companion object.  Methods that look like NameOfClass.someMethod are always from the companion object.  (Unlike, say, Java, where they are static methods on the original class.)  The Scaladocs have a little O and C icon next to the class names on the left, and at the top of the class page there's a link (not very obvious) in the top header to the companion object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`None` is an instance of `Option[Nothing]`.  But `Option` is covariant in its type parameter, and `Nothing` is a subtype of everything.

This means that `None` is a subtype of `Option[A]`.  Just say so:

```
None: Option[A]
```

But type inference can usually do it for you.  If you create the function in advance,

```
val default = (c: C) => None
```

then you'll get the wrong return type and need to specify it, but `withDefaultValue` should already know the type of your map.

Comment: OP has Map from String to Function1: `HashMap[String, C=>Option[A]]`, so `withDefaultValue` should actually take `(_ => None)` and `withDefault` should take `(_ => _ => None)`